# Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
Here is my Frangment
```

Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

I am trying to implement fragments in my work but failed and posting question after spending about non stop 8 hours. plz help thanks.
    Here is my Frangment
Using Fragment to display the description of Listview items onclicking. Listview items are in an activity and description is in a fragment

```
    package academic.organizer;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class assignment_description extends Fragment {
    TextView description;
         @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_description, container,    false);


            }

         public void setText(String item) {
             TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.assignment_description);
             view.setText(item);
           }



    }
```

Here is Layout for fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assignment_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Assignment Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>



Function for making listview
public void viewAssignments(){

        Log.d("test","test");
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new tableCustomList(this, R.layout.lvadapter,assignments);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("Registering for context menu");
        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }



//here is what i want to do on listitemclick
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        assignment_description fragment =  (assignment_description) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
              fragment.setText("setting text");}



Here is layout for class containing function viewassignements()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/bg015"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textSize="3dp" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="academic.organizer.assignment_description" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>




Here are Log Details............./
11-11 02:26:47.727: E/AndroidRuntime(17738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-11 02:26:47.727: E/AndroidRuntime(17738):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)



**where you can see my layout has a listview with id list.**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, Im still new at this so i do apologize if that is wrong

```
 public void setText(String item) {
             TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.assignment_description);
             view.setText(item);
           }
```

to

```
public void setText(String item) {
             TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
             view.setText(item);
           }
```

Comment: jford thanks for your interest but listen here in seetText(String item).... i am refering to Text view of layout for fragment where R.id.list resides in layout for function viewassignments()

Comment: hey it was worth a shot!

Comment: you use assignment_description as your class, layout, and id?

Comment: i use assignment_description  as a class dear.

Comment: its more than a class

Comment: Soory couldn't get you, what do you mean more than a class